# Get audio duration on Chrome for Android

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm getting the audio/video duration of a file without appending it to the screen. **"Using the same code"**, when I try to get the video duration on both sides it works as expected. But when using audio files it says that **the duration is 0** on Android, but it works on a desktop computer.

```
// Only working on Desktop
var audio = new Audio(url);

// Hide audio player
// player.appendChild(audio);

audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  alert(audio.duration);
});
```

And the below code is working:

```
// Working on Desktop and Android
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.src = url;

// Hide video
// player.appendChild(video);

video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  alert(video.duration);
});
```

Comment: do you try to play the audio/video, or is that it? phones don't preload like desktops do, but a preload=all attrib might help. after you tap "play" on an audio with controls, you should be able to get the duration once the loadedmetadata fires.

Comment: @dandavis It's working. It'd be a bug as the same code did not work two months ago. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Using the **durationchange** event is much easier. First the 0 is being output, but as soon as the file is loaded (that's where **loadedmetadata** fails I guess) the updated and real duration will be output.

```
audio.addEventListener('durationchange', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.duration); //FIRST 0, THEN REAL DURATION
});
```

**OLD WAY (ABOVE IS MUCH FASTER)**

Looks like this "bug" (if this is actually a real bug) is still around. Chrome (40) for Android still outputs 0 as the audio files duration. Researching the web didn't get me a solution but I found out the bug also occurs on iOS. I figured I should post my fix here for you guys.

While *audio.duration* outputs 0, logging *audio* outputs the object and you can see that the duration is displayed just right there. All this is happening in the **loadedmetadata** event.

```
audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.duration); //0
});
```

If you log audio.duration in the **timeupdate** event though, the real duration is being output. To only output it once you could do something like:

```
var fix = true;
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
    if(fix === true) {
        console.log(e.target.duration); //REAL DURATION
        fix = false;
    }
    console.log(e.target.currentTime); //UPDATED TIME POSITION
});
```

I'm not sure why all this is happening. But let's be happy it's nothing serious.

Answer (score 5):

There is a different approach you can try but, if duration doesn't work with your device (which IMO is a bug) then it's likely this doesn't either; worth a shot though:

```
audio.seekable.end(audio.seekable.length-1);
```

or even

```
audio.buffered.end(audio.buffered.length-1);
```

though the latter is dependent on content being loaded which in this case probably then won't help.

Comment: Working on desktop but unfortunately not on Android (tested on Chrome for Android version 35). Thank you.

Comment: @honzzz Is your code right? Mine is working well now. https://github.com/miguelripoll/Cast/blob/master/www/scripts/app.js#L152

Comment: @PhilDunphy23 - are you saying it's working with Chrome for Android? Which version of Android do you have?