# can not get audio duration in chrome - js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I can not get `audio.duration` in chrome ! 
 This code is ok in firefox !

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d5pgzbxu/4/)

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var audio = document.getElementById('mine');
    alert(audio.duration)
});
```

HTML:

```
<audio src='theurl.mp3' controls id='mine'></audio>
```

Comment: [Perhaps this question will help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719542/get-audio-duration-on-chrome-for-android)

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var audio = $('#mine')[0];
    alert(audio.duration);
});
```

On DOM ready means the document is ready for manipulation, but not all elements are loaded(images or iframes, for example). In this case the controls are loaded, but not the audio file.

You could even consider using a setTimeout to get the duration. Testing this example I tryed:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var audio = $('#mine')[0];
    setTimeout(function(){alert(audio.duration);},20);
});
```

And it worked.

Comment: Can you take a look at this topic ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638065/audio-controll-backward-forward-buttons-java-script