# audio controll - backward , forward buttons - Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When hold on a next button audio player make faster ...

The code represents everything

> main question : How to continue to normal ?

**Here is my try**

http://jsfiddle.net/1t6g8oLg/

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    var audio = document.getElementById('mine');
    audio.addEventListener('durationchange', function (e) {
        $('.btn-forward').mousedown(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                audio.currentTime += 10;
            }, 200);
        }).mouseup(function () {
            // Continue to normal
        });

        $('.btn-backward').mousedown(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                audio.currentTime += 10;
            }, 200);
        }).mouseup(function () {
            // Continue to normal
        });
    });

});
```

> on Hold ! <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove your EventListener and add a ClearInterval to stop the loop:

```
$('.btn-forward').mousedown(function () {
    audio.pause();
    intervalo = setInterval(function () {
        audio.currentTime += 10;
    }, 200);
}).mouseup(function () {
    clearInterval(intervalo);
    audio.play();
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alezanatta/pcqucbu5/)